# Compatibility with different resolutions/inches

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-screen-support

I'm developing an app and my Constraint Layout isn't compatible with any screen size.

I have a button with the following width and height:

```
android:layout_width="283dp"
android:layout_height="57dp"
```

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhSSo.png) how it look using a Google Pixel.
And [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2IL8.png) how it looks using a Nexus S

I also sent the apk to a person that has an Galaxy J7 (1280x720, 5.5'), and my buttons, textviews and imageviews don't fit well in the screen, just like the Nexus S (800x480, 4').

After reading the documentation and other sources, I got that I can create different layouts for different screens (hdpi, for example, which is the case of the Nexus S).

But it looks that the problem is more related to the display inches than with the device dpi.
Because the Nexus S has an 800x480, hdpi and 4' screen. But when I change to a 800x480, mdpi and 5.1' screen (1.1' more inch), it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEnff.png) way better than in the Nexus S, even with a lower dpi (mdpi). It also looks better than in the Galaxy J7 real device, even with a lower screen size (5.1' x 5.5') and resolution (800x480 vs 1280x720).

So, how can it fit well in a 800x480 5.1' mdpi screen, but not in a 1280x720 5.5' Galaxy J7 and in a 800x480 4.0' hdpi screen (Nexus S)?

Also, if I create a virtual device with the same screen specs of the Galaxy J7 real device (1280x720 and 5.5'), It fits really well, unlike the real phone.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/intuit/ssp and https://github.com/intuit/sdp if you don't want to make multi ``dimens.xml`` yourself. It not make your app show exactly the same on all devices, but it will look better than using pure dp in your case.

Comment: @ThuanTang I've seen these libraries but I was a little afraid of using it, as it isn't an official library. I solved my problem using `android:autoSizeTextType`, 
 `layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `layout_constraintHeight_percent`.

Comment: Those library just contains many ``dimens.xml`` file, you can go and check their source code. ``layout_constraintWidth_percent`` and ``layout_constraintHeight_percent`` sure good in your case but it cost a lot of performance compare to ``dimens.xml``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your fixed size (what you are currently giving to your views) with something more responsive.

If this was your non responsive button:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="400dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Just replace it with this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

For every phone, small or large this button will adjust according to the screen size and will take `30%` of the screen width and `50%` of the screen Width.
This is how you can make one screen responsive to all screen sizes and not create a lot of layouts for different screens.

Comment: Thanks! This is way better than using a predefined size in `dp`. Althought it fixes the problem with buttons, it doesn't work with `TextViews`, but I found out how to autosize `TextViews` with `android:autoSizeTextType`, which also helped me a lot.

Comment: You can also use [ssp library](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) for your texts

Comment: Yes, I found out this library, but I was a little afraid of using it, because it isn't an official library. But I'll also try it.

Comment: Well, you can always find some new library and try it, maybe you will find it usfull.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to use Adobe XD and use it to determine the size

```
android:layout_width="283dp"
android:layout_height="57dp"
```

and after that extract the pictures for all sizes
Then make the width and height wrap_content
In the XML file

Comment: I'm not really good in design and I've never used Adobe XD. But I'll take a look at it, It'll be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These images are OK, it's not a problem itself. That's usually what happens when you set the width and height manually.

Best thing you can do is set the right constraints and then set width and/or height to 0dp. This will make your view expand as much as possible without breaking any constraint. This way you will still get different widths and heights, but hopefully less noticable ones.

Be aware that if you set top and bottom constraints to parent, and you set the height to 0dp, it will expand to fill its contraints, it will fill your whole parent.

And for positioning you can use guidelines if you want. A a horizontal guideline in 50% will be in the middle of the screen in every phone. So you can constrain views to that as well.

Comment: I defined my right/left margins to 64dp, and top/bottom margins to 40dp, it looks good in Nexus S, but If I change to Google Pixel, it looks way bigger than I'd like to. I think that the best would be to create a new layout to a different screen. But I'm not understanding really well in which aspect of the screen this should be based. Because, as I said, it's weird that the layout fits well in a mdpi screen, but not in a hdpi screen that has less inches, because the new layout should be based on the dpi, not on the inches, right?